# Spring MVC- class org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService not available in 4.3.3.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm deploying my first spring mvc project in tomcat. But, its giving the problem of class not found exception of "DefaultConversionService" I'm using 4.3.3.RELEASE version of spring. Am I missing any dependencies or any dependency is wrong in my pom.xml?

Here is the pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>CNC</groupId>
<artifactId>CNC</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>

<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency> 


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- spring-context which provides core functionality -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>



</dependencies>

</project>
```

### Error log

```
  Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.<init>(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:41)
at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.<init>(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:42)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.<init>(AbstractEnvironment.java:110)
at org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment.<init>(StandardEnvironment.java:54)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment.<init>(StandardServletEnvironment.java:44)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.createEnvironment(HttpServletBean.java:215)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.getEnvironment(HttpServletBean.java:205)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:126)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1238)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1151)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:828)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and did some research. It seems that there was a glitch in the release of the "**spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar**" artifact. It missed the "**core**" package, thus creating class not found errors even if correctly included.

The package has been [re-updated the 19th of September 2016](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22spring-core%22) with an (apparently) corrected one.

So deleting the "org.springframework" packages (all, just to be sure) in your local maven repository, then re-building your project, downloading the new versions, should magically solve the problem!

Hope this helps (it did help in my case)!

Comment: It did not work for me. Or maybe there is some other conflict in my jars.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the spring-binding dependency.

A quick google search shows the DefaultConversionService is located in this dependency.

https://1maven.com/classname-packaging?pk=&cl=DefaultConversionService

Comment: No.. still the same.. its poining to the same location org.springframework.core.convert.support

Comment: I would just do a double check to make sure the class/jar is in your artifact. If it is there then it has to be some issue with your deployment of the war file. Explode it with the command line or some other tool.

Comment: other classes are present except the needed..i mean when i run the project itself its missing..

Comment: I am not sure i understand what you mean. Post the output of 'mvn dependency:tree' from your project, somewhere there should be a compile dependency for spring-binding

Comment: I got it now after deleting the jar from .m2, but getting the same error

Comment: plz invite for chat.. so that i can describe u more

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem here, I also had the similar `springframework` packages as you do.

But I solved it by removing:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
   <version>2.5.6</version>
</dependency>
```

You must clear you target directory when you change your `pom.xml`.

And, you don't need to add the aop or context package in dependencies, it will be generated automatically.

Hope it will work to you!